# On a computer with multiple NUMA nodes and large memory, will Linux kernel mostly run on NUMA node 0?

Tags: linux, memory

While reading the "Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager" book, it discusses how memory is managed in a NUMA aware approach. My question is on a large host with multiple NUMA nodes and 'large' memory, will the Linux kernel mostly run on NUMA node 0 and allocate kernel memory on NUMA node 0?

For example, on a machine with 2 NUMA nodes and 256G RAM, will the kernel memory mostly run on node 0, does this mean it will be less performant when Kernel access memory on the remote node (node 1)?

Comment: The kernel isn't a separate task; it can be "running on" any node on which a task makes a system call.

Comment: How about the system daemon tasks, such as kstaled, kswapd, should it be a case by case discussion or is there any general rule that applies to the whole kernel?